# How to implement apply in my code (without changing call functions)

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to understand how to properly use apply with objects and arguments, instead of using if else statements.

My current code:

```js
var log = function(call, name) {
  return function(a, b, c) {
    if (c === undefined) {
      console.log(name + "(" + a + b + ")" + "=" + call(a, b));
    } else {
      console.log(name + "(" + a + b + c + ")" + "=" + call(a, b, c));
    }
  }
};

//Includes two call functions
```

EDIT: More readable

Comment: `console.log(name + "(" + [].join.call(arguments, ",") + ")=>" + callback.apply(null, arguments));`

Comment: You can use `Function.name` instead of having to pass the function name. You can also use spread syntax (or `apply` in your case) to pass arguments.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `apply`, then you would just call `apply` with the first parameter as `null` and the second parameter as a list of the arguments:

```
console.log(name + "(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")" + "=>" + callback.apply(null, [a, b, c]));
```

```js
var wrapLog = function(callback, name) {
  return function(a, b, c) {
    console.log(name + "(" + a + "," + b + "," + c + ")" + "=>" + callback.apply(null, [a, b, c]));
  }
};

var area = function(x, y) { //don't change this function
  return x * y;
};
var logArea = wrapLog(area, "area");



logArea(5, 3); // area(5, 3) => 15
logArea(3, 2); // area(3, 2) => 6

var volume = function(x, y, z) { //don't change this function
  return x * y * z;
};
var logVolume = wrapLog(volume, "volume");

logVolume(5, 3, 2); // volume(5, 3, 2) => 30
logVolume(3, 2, 4); // volume(3, 2, 4) => 24
```

But you might consider converting the arguments in the function returned by `wrapLog` to an array *in the parameters themselves* for the least syntax noise:

```
return function(...args) {
  console.log(`${name}(${args}) => ${callback.apply(null, args)}`);
}
```

```js
var wrapLog = function(callback, name) {
  return function(...args) {
    console.log(`${name}(${args}) => ${callback.apply(null, args)}`);
  }
};

var area = function(x, y) { //don't change this function
  return x * y;
};
var logArea = wrapLog(area, "area");



logArea(5, 3); // area(5, 3) => 15
logArea(3, 2); // area(3, 2) => 6

var volume = function(x, y, z) { //don't change this function
  return x * y * z;
};
var logVolume = wrapLog(volume, "volume");

logVolume(5, 3, 2); // volume(5, 3, 2) => 30
logVolume(3, 2, 4); // volume(3, 2, 4) => 24
```

Comment: If I made a mistake, could someone explain? Thanks